# can't run npm run dev

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

After i run

```
php artisan ui vue --auth,
```

i am doing npm install without problem, but when i run npm run dev it show error like this

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div class="container">
|         <div class="row justify-content-center">

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

how to solve that error?

Comment: What version of Laravel UI are you using? Also are you using vite or webpack (mix)?

Comment: how to see version of my laravel ui?

Comment: Should be in your composer.json

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [laravel mix documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue), in order to use Vue js, you must use the `mix.vue()` command in the webpack.mix.js file (in the root folder of your project).

For exemple this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
.sass("resources/scss/app.scss", "public/css");
```

instead of this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass("resources/scss/app.scss", "public/css");
```